# Why is this list showing as empty, but tuples will parse fine?

Tags: erlang

I'm converting a tuple full of erlang objects to maps which I plan to convert to JSON later.

The tileJSON function is being called with a 2 element tuple. I'm expecting to see a list of rows with tiles in them in the map for each tableCache element. Instead I see this:

```
#{"availableTablePids" => ["<0.477.0>"],
  "hall" => [],
  "tableCache" => [],
  "tablePids" => ["<0.477.0>"]}
```

Setting tileJSON to return a tuple like this:

```
tileJSON({Status, Sitter}) ->
  {atomJSON(Status), atomJSON(Sitter)}.
```

I get this data:

```
#{"availableTablePids" => ["<0.477.0>"],
  "hall" => [],
  "tableCache" => [#{"actions" => #{"current" => "x","o" => #{"next" => 0,"now" => 0},"x" => #{"next" => 0,"now" => 2}},
     "board" => [[{"spawn","x"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"}],
      [{"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"ridge","null"},
       {"empty","null"}],
      [{"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"ridge","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"}],
      [{"empty","null"},
       {"ridge","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"}],
      [{"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"empty","null"},
       {"spawn","o"}]],
     "clock" => #{"current" => "x","o" => 3000,"status" => "unstarted","x" => 3000}}],
  "tablePids" => ["<0.477.0>"]}

atomJSON(Atom) -> atom_to_list(Atom).

tileJSON({Status, Sitter}) ->
  [atomJSON(Status), atomJSON(Sitter)].

rowJSON(Row) ->
  lists:map(fun(Tile) -> tileJSON(Tile) end, Row).

boardJSON(Board) ->
  lists:map(fun(Row) -> rowJSON(Row) end, Board).

tableCacheJSON(Cache) ->
  lists:map(fun(#{actions := Actions, clock := Clock, board := Board}) -> 
    #{"actions" => actionsJSON(Actions),
      "clock" => clockJSON(Clock),
      "board" => boardJSON(Board)
      }
   end, Cache).
```

The program is not crashing. What's wrong with my original tileJSON function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, can't replicate with the code you've shown. It could be that you got confused about what code you had currently compiled and loaded compared to what you had in your editor. But if you still think something is wrong, please try to recreate the situation that failed and post the exact code causing it.